# Better way to check when variable equals to another value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a variable that I need to check frequently when my game is running. To simplify this, the check is: `if (score >= achievement1) {do something}`.

It seemed overkill to put this check in the `Update()` function which is called every frame;

So instead, I call the `InvokeRepeating` function in the `Start ();` function:

```
InvokeRepeating ("checkscoreforachievement", 0f, 2f);
```

Is this smart or is there a better way doing this? End result should be that within a few seconds after achieving a certain score, the achievement is triggered.

The reason I'm asking is that there are a few more things I need to do regularly when my game is running, so I'll end up with quite a few of these processes. Wondering if that isn't too much of a resource drain. Can't find good documentation on this subject.

Comment: Maybe you could check it when changing the score and trigger it from there. 

   `score++; //or how every much you add
   if (score >= achievement1) 
  {
   do something
   }`

Comment: I was just going to suggest what @TheSkimek was about to say! I guess you could also use `InvokeRepeating` and then when your condition is true, stop checking for it. As in `if (score >= achievement) {CancelInvoke("yourMethodName") // as well as do something}`

Comment: You may want to explore the observer pattern, that is usually what is used to do this sort of thing.. Your gameObject that handles the score could be observable, so that when the score is changed it will notify listeners that have subscribed to it with a call back the callback can check if the condition you want. This will avoid polluting your gameloop with that sort of test.

Comment: "Wondering if that isn't too much of a resource drain" dont wonder, test if it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `InvokeRepeating` is not better in this case.

It's not better because you are calling that function every 2 seconds which means that when `score >= achievement1` evaluates to `true`, it will take about 2 seconds to detect that. Also, `InvokeRepeating` uses reflection which is slow. There is no advantage of using it here. Using the `Update` function like you are currently doing it is totally fine.

---

A much more better solution than using the `Update` function would be to check if `score >= achievement1` *only when score is changed with auto property*.

```
public int achievement1 = 0;
private float _score;

public float score
{
    get
    {
        return _score;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_score != value)
        {
            _score = value;

            if (_score >= achievement1)
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will only do the check when the `score` variable is set or changed instead of every frame but the `Update` code is fine.

Comment: Problem is that my score is changing up or down 10 times per second...yet it doesn't really matter if the achievement is triggered 2 seconds or so later, the user won't notice. My main concern is this: I want to build many types of achievements, not all based on the score alone. If I need to check them in Update  by running a 'checkachievement method' with many if statements in it, I am afraid things slow down or drain resources...now, I do realize that there are other ways to checking things, but my scoring method is complicated already...

Comment: Even with your comment, my answer is still valid. `InvokeRepeating` should not be used for this. 2.You can use the auto property I mentioned above. That should do it without checking it in the Update function very frame. It will only do the checking only when the variable is modified. Just replace the variable you will be checking every frame with auto property like the `score` variable in my answer.

Comment: `Problem is that my score is changing up or down 10 times per second` - Disregarding system performance bottlenecks, `Update` is called at least 30 times per second (mobile devices), and can be as high as 300+, depending on game, system and disabled Vsync... Checking a variable when it's changed is **the** way of doing this for a reason, but even if that wasn't the case, 10/s instead of 30+/s is still a huge improvement if your concern is wasteful checks... Which is probably a case of [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/191857) in the first place.

Comment: @AlmightyR That's what I tried to tell OP. Using the `Update` function fine for this.

Comment: @Killbert If you **really** want to insist on a timed check, then a simple `delta-time` pattern will do: `/*outside Update*/ float elapsedTime=0f; float maxElapsedTime=0.25f;` --- `/*inside Update*/ elapsedTime+=Time.deltaTime; if(elapsedTime>=0.25f){elapsedTime%=maxElapsedTime;/*do your check and whatever else here*/}` --- **NOTE:** For timed checks regarding feedback to users, keep it between `0.2f` and `0.333f`, because that matches average human reaction time. --- But it's _**very strongly**_ recommended to just use the `observable` pattern ("checking when changed") instead.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers and comments. Most helpful. Only thing I don't understand is this: from a performance point of view: what is the impact of a InvokeRepeating call? Regardless of my specific issue: what does "InvokeRepeating uses *reflection* which is slow" mean?

Comment: Impact of InvokeRepeating  is that it is slow. Google "C# reflection" to see how it works. Any function that you can pass a string into it as a function so that it will be called later on is using a reflection. Since you pass the name of the function(checkscoreforachievement) to the InvokeRepeating function, it does not have a direct reference to the checkscoreforachievement function. It will have to search your script, then find the `checkscoreforachievement` function. This process is slower than calling the checkscoreforachievement function directly or using the `Action` feature in C#.

Comment: @Programmer Brilliant summarized explanation! I hate to admit it, but I couldn't explain this stuff so clearly with just 600 chars. I recommend adding it to the answer in some form, just to make the reasons why reflection is evil in this case clear to any future readers as well. =)

Comment: Thanks. I think most C# programmers knew this already  about reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Some other users have pointed this out similar things already, but essentially when the score is changed, call a function of your own to check. Don't invoke repeating or use update because honestly, it's just unnecessary to do it so infrequently or so frequently respectively.

Literally set it that when your score is incremented or decremented (changed in any way) you call the function to check.

You could also create an Array of achievements, and check the index before you even call the function to display/update the achievement:

```
if(arrayname[i] != "Unlocked"){
//Call function;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realized I need to rephrase my question, so I edited it, see above.